# lambda function of if else statement in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, lambda

I would like to overwrite a variable according to a specific condition and in the other cases keep its original value.

in pseudo code: if age < 2 then id=99, else id

I miss the "else id" style sentence

```
raw_data1 = {'id': [1,2,3,5],
    'age': [0, np.nan, 10, 2]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data1, columns = ['id','age'])



df1['id'] = np.where(df1['age']<2,99)

df1['id']=df['age'].apply(lambda x:99 if x<2)
```

Comment: don't `apply` just add the `else` condition to your `where`: `df1['id'] = np.where(df1['age']<2,99, df1['age'])`, if you insist on `apply` then the form is `df1['id']=df1['age'].apply(lambda x:99 if x<2 else x)`

Comment: my text was not clear, I meant something to obtain this:df1['id'] = np.where(df1['age']<2,99,df1['id']) , but I cannot manage to do the apply version

Answer (score 0):

```
df1['id'] = np.where(df1['age']<2,99,df1['age'])
```

Should work.

```
where(condition,true,false)
```

You better check [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).